# Azure DevTest Labs custom artifact not taking effect

Tags: azure, chocolatey, azure-devtest-labs

I cloned the notepad++ artifact from GitHub and am trying to install VLC using Chocolatey.

I'm looking into the chocolatey log files and the log files have no trace of VLC in them.

I can see the custom artifact getting picked up from my Git repo in VSTS and shown inside the Azure portal as valid artifact.
I came across Jonathan Rajotte comment over here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/devtest-lab-artifact-author/  saying that my artifacts in the repo have to be enclosed by a top level folder.
Now my repo structure  /privateArtifacts/BasicSamples/Artifacts

I don’t see any errors while the artifacts are getting provisioned in the VM.
What am I doing wrong that’s preventing the artifact from taking effect?